# How to import all macros, derives, and procedural macros in Rust 2018 without using extern crate?

Tags: rust, rust-2018

I'm experimenting with [Rust Edition 2018](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/index.html). In Rust 2015 you use

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
```

for importing macros. In Rust 2018 `extern crate` is probably unidiomatic. Is there a way, to import all macros from the crate without `extern crate`? For simple macros, [importing it in the modules](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html) is fine, but complicated macros depend on several other macros, which is unhandy.

Comment: *complicated macros depend on several other macros* — As of Rust 1.30, macros can [import the helper macros they need](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53017178/155423), preventing this root problem.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any way of importing *only* all the macros, but if you are fine with importing all the essential objects a crate provides, you should usually get all the macros by writing:

```
use the_crate_with_macros::*;
```

or

```
use the_crate_with_macros::prelude::*; // if available
```

This also works in Rust 2015 starting in version 1.30.

Answer (score 4):

As you already stated you can import a single macro via

```
use foo::mac1;
```

To import multiple macros at once you can either use [nested imports](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/nested-imports-with-use.html)

```
use foo::{mac1, mac2, mac3};
```

or rely on the crate author that they will let you import it via a single glob, e.g.

```
use foo::macros::*;
```