# How to conditionally change a small part of a Rust macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I am building a crate which has the feature `foo`. This crate has a macro `bar!` that does subtly different things based on whether `foo` is set.

I could duplicate the entire macro:

```
#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
macro_rules! bar {
    // Lots of rules...

    ( A ) => {
        B
    }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "foo"))]
macro_rules! bar {
    // Lots of rules...

    ( A ) => {
        C
    }
}
```

That's a lot of error-prone duplication. Two approaches that don't work:

- We can't move the `cfg` inside the macro, because then it will expand in the crate user's scope, which  does not have feature `foo` appropriately set.
- We can't use a `#[doc(hidden)] #[macro_export] macro_rules! bar_priv_impl__` helper macro and use `#[cfg]` on the helper macro since Rust 1.30, because users can now request `use mycrate::bar;` to only import the `bar!` macro, giving errors about how `bar_priv_impl__!` is not defined.

Is there any way that's better than full macro duplication? It gets really bad if you have N features you're testing on, as you need *2<sup>n</sup>* duplications.

Comment: *only import the `bar!` macro*  — FWIW, people could do that before via `#[macro_use(foo, bar)]`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Nope, I tried using `#[cfg]` as a verb there. I reworded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since Rust 1.30 [...] because users can now [...] only import the `bar!` macro

Actually, this solution is *only* possible in Rust 1.30 because of the ability to import macros like normal. Remember that your macro can *also* have `use` statements!:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! bar {
    ($val:expr) => {{
        use $crate::__bar_foo;
        __bar_foo!($val)
    }}
}

#[cfg(feature = "foo")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! __bar_foo {
    ($val:expr) => ($val + 1)
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "foo"))]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! __bar_foo {
    ($val:expr) => ($val - 1)
}
```

You can also fully-qualify your helper macro invocation:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! bar {
    ($val:expr) => ($crate::__bar_foo!($val))
}
```